# How is the normalized probability function used in the variance?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, probability, statistics

For context this is the very beginning of stat mech. I understand how the definition of the mean was used but I don't know how we went from part 2 to 3 (going left to right in the series of equations).[image: stat mech course notes on Characteristics of probability distributions]

Comment: It is a weighted average.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an explanation on each step for completion.

1. For the second equality, we are using the definition of average, i.e $$\langle f(n)\rangle \equiv \sum_{n=0}^N f(n)P_N(n)$$
   for specific $f(n) = (n-\langle n \rangle)^2$
2. For the third equality, we are just expanding the square, i.e $(a-b)^2 = a^2+b^2 -2ab$
3. For the fourth equality, which is likely the most confusing, we are doing a couple things. First, we distributed $P_N(n)$ on each of the terms in the bracket. This means that we have these 3 terms $$\sum n^2 P_N(n) + \langle n^2\rangle P_N(n)-2\langle n\rangle nP_N(n)$$. We can separate the sum into 3 sums (they all have the same range but I am not going t explicitely write it out). $$\sum n^2 P_N(n) +\sum \langle n^2\rangle P_N(n)-2\sum\langle n\rangle nP_N(n)$$

For the first term, we are just using the definition of of average as above, except with $f(n) = n^2$, we get $$\sum n^2 P_N(n) = \langle n^2 \rangle$$. For the second, we are taking $\langle n\rangle^2 $ out of the sum because it doesn't depend on $n$ (we already summed over $n$ in the $\langle\rangle$, as its an average independent of $n$) so $$\sum \langle n\rangle^2 P_N(n) = \langle n\rangle^2 \sum P_N(n) =\langle n\rangle^2 $$

where we used the fact that the probability is normalized in the last part, $\sum P_N(n) = 1$.

For the last term, we are doing the same thing as before, taking the $\langle n\rangle$ out of the sum and then recognizing what remains as the average$$-2\sum\langle n\rangle nP_N(n) = -2\langle n\rangle\sum nP_N(n) =-2\langle n\rangle\langle n\rangle = -2\langle n\rangle^2 $$

Then, putting these all together, we are left with
$$\langle n^2 \rangle+\langle n\rangle^2-2\langle n\rangle^2 = \langle n^2 \rangle-\langle n\rangle^2$$ which is the desired result.